# How to override default docker container command or revert to previous container state?

Tags: docker

I have a docker image running a wordpress installation. The image by executes the apache server as default command. So when you stop the apache service the container exits.

The problem comes after messing up the apache server config. The container cannot start and I cannot recover the image contents.

My options are to either override the command that the container runs or revert last file system changes to a previous state.

Is any of these things possible? Alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to copy the contents out you can use the command below with a more specific path.

> sudo docker cp containername:/var/ /varbackup/

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#cp

The file system is also accessible from the host.  Run the command below and in the volumes section at the bottom it should have a path to where your file system modifications are stored.
 **This is not a good permanent solution.**

> docker inspect containername

If you re-create the container later you should look into keeping your data outside of the container and linking it into the container as a virtual path when you create the container.  If you link your apache config file into the container this way you can edit it while the container is not running

Managing Data in Containers
http://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

Edit 1:  Not suggesting this as a best practice but it should work.
This should display the path to the apache2.conf on the host.
Replace some-wordpress with your container name.

```
CONTAINER_ID=$(docker inspect -f   '{{.Id}}' some-wordpress)
sudo find /var/lib/docker/ -name apache2.conf | grep $CONTAINER_ID
```

Comment: Thanks @nathan-smith, I've been able to extract the contents with the cp command. Is there any way to overwrite a file inside the container? My problem is a misconfiguration on apache2.conf file. If I can overwrite it would be ok.

Comment: I know where the file is, but I need to overwrite the container copy with one from the host. The cp command allows to do the opposite. Which is ok for backing up contents.

Comment: Not sure how to format the comments so I edited my post above.  The path to the apache.conf will look like /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/019afa3b3f32f85aef4214fe22300932a1afd130a6da1745304884caa0b198db/etc/apache2/apache2.conf  just edit that file and try to restart the container.

Comment: Now I get it! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

When you start a container with `docker run`, you can provide a command to run inside the container.  This will override any command specified in the image.  For example:

```
docker run -it some/container bash
```

If you have modified the configuration inside the *container*, it would not affect the content of the *image*.  So you can "revert the filesystem changes" just by starting a new container from the original image...in which case you still have the *original* image available.

The only way to that changes inside a container affect an image are if you use the `docker commit` command to generate a *new* image containing the changes you made in the container.

Comment: TL;DR So I should commit the container generating an image and rerun a new container from the created image with the command line prompt. Right?

Comment: If your goal is to save changes you've made in an existing container, yes, that should do the trick.

Comment: The problem here is I cannot attach to the image. As soon as it is started it exits. It ends up reporting: "State unavailable for container [...] The container may have been cleaned up already [...]". I have been able to copy the contents out as @nathan-smith suggested. I'd be able to correct the problem If I could overwrite apache2.conf file inside the container.

Comment: It seems like you could solve that with a Dockerfile using `FROM <originalimage>` and a `COPY apache2.conf /path/to/apache2.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of overriding the default command of a docker image. Here you have two:

1. If you have an image with a default CMD command, you can simply override it in `docker run` giving as last argument the command (with its argument) you wish to run (`Usage: docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`)
2. Create a wrapper image with `BASE` image the one you want to override the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. Example

   `FROM my_image
    CMD ["my-new-cmd"]`

Also, you can try to revert the changes in different ways:

1. If you have the Dockerfile of the image you want to revert, simple rewrite the changes into Dockerfile and run again `docker build` process.
2. If you don't have the Dockerfile and you built the image committing the changes, you can use `docker history <IMAGE_NAME>:tag`, locate the IMAGE_ID of the commit you want, and run that commit or tag that commit with the name (and tag) you wish (using `-f` option if you are overriding a tag name). Example:

`$ docker history docker_io_package:latest`

`$ docker tag -f c7b38f258a80 docker_io_package:latest`

Comment: Not the case. This is a built image with significant changes.

Comment: In that case I would start from the broken image, fix the problems and save it with the problems fixed. You can do this: a) Launching your image with `docker run -it myimage /bin/bash`, fixing it, and committing `docker commit <CONT_ID> my_image:mytag`; or b) Using a `Dockerfile` from your image, fix in the docker file, and then building it again with `docker build`

Comment: The point is I cannot fix the problem. The container runs a the apache server as the command. The apache is misconfigured so the container exits as soon as it starts. So unless I find a way to rewrite the apache2.conf in the container, I'll have to regenerate the image from the start.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of  `docker inspect <IMAGE_NAME>`

Answer (score 0):

If it requires starting a command with a set of arguments, for example

`ls -al /bin`

try to make it like that

`docker run --entrypoint ls -it debian /bin -al`

where `ls` goes after `--entrypoint` and all arguments are placed after the image name